# I get a status code error when I run this route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying for a week now to be able to write changes to MySQL database I finally got it to do it, but I get a 404 error and the program crashes what am I doing wrong?, here is the code..

```
router.post('/edit', (req, res) => {
  const {
    user_id = req.params.user_id,
    timesPD = req.body.timesPD,
    chkCarbs = req.body.chkCarbs,
    chkInsulin = req.body.chkInsulin,
    typInsulin = req.body.typInsulin,
    chkBP = req.body.chkBP
  } = req.query;

  const sql =
    `UPDATE preferences
    SET user_id=${user_id}, timesPD=${timesPD}, chkCarbs=${chkCarbs},
    chkInsulin=${chkInsulin}, typInsulin=${typInsulin}, chkBP=${chkBP}
    WHERE user_id=${user_id};`;

  connection.query(sql,
    [user_id, timesPD, chkCarbs, chkInsulin, typInsulin, chkBP],
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err.message);
      } else {
        res.send('Rows affected: ', results.affetedRows);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I'm using node version 12.14.1 and the terminal error I get is

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: Rows 
affected:
[0]     at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:246:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:237:8)
[0]     at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:720:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send 
(D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> 
(D:\vscode\bgtracker\routes\preferences.js:90:13)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> 
(D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
[0]     at Query._callback 
(D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:491:16) 
[0]     at Query.Sequence.end
```

(D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
[0]     at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
[0]     at Query.OkPacket (D:\vscode\bgtracker\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:72:10) {
[0]   code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'

Comment: Can you provide terminal error output?

Comment: I think your ```res.send('Rows affected: ', results.affetedRows);``` should be using a `+` instead of a `,`. The docs for ```send()``` don't show a two-arg version, so it probably thinks you're trying to send a status code of "Rows affected: ", which is invalid.

Comment: It worked thank you so much